# Why `tsc --noEmit --watch` never ends in vite/react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, tsc

I have a vite/react project migrated from CRA for a while, and I just mentioned that when I run `tsc` command to check the project for typescript errors it will never finish. So maybe someone can help to fix this problem?

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.39.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20.10.0 <21.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@datadog/browser-logs": "^5.10.0",
    "@datadog/browser-rum": "^5.10.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.10",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^6.1.10",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.10",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.17",
    "@hookform/error-message": "^2.0.1",
    "@marker.io/browser": "^0.19.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "@tanstack/match-sorter-utils": "^8.8.4",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.7.9",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.3.2",
    "@twilio/video-processors": "2.1.0",
    "@twilio/voice-sdk": "2.9.0",
    "@unleash/proxy-client-react": "^4.2.2",
    "@zoom/videosdk": "^1.10.7",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.5",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.0.9",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.1",
    "chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4": "^1.0.4",
    "classnames": "^2.5.1",
    "compare-versions": "^6.1.0",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.3",
    "html-react-parser": "^5.1.8",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "linkify-react": "^4.1.3",
    "linkifyjs": "^4.1.2",
    "query-string": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-auth-code-input": "^3.2.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.2",
    "react-custom-scrollbars-2": "^4.5.0",
    "react-day-picker": "^8.7.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^4.0.12",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^4.1.1",
    "react-idle-timer": "^5.5.3",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.5.3",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.1.0",
    "react-lottie-player": "^1.5.4",
    "react-modern-drawer": "^1.2.0",
    "react-number-format": "^5.3.1",
    "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^5.1.7",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.5.2",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "react-use": "^17.4.3",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.11.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.6",
    "stylis": "^4.3.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.1.7",
    "twilio-video": "^2.27.0",
    "unleash-proxy-client": "^3.3.1",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "yet-another-react-lightbox": "^3.15.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "madge": "madge --circular --extensions ts,tsx,js,jsx src",
    "postinstall": "rimraf public/virtualbackground && copyfiles -f node_modules/@twilio/video-processors/dist/build/* public/virtualbackground",
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest",
    "coverage": "vitest run --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.cjs,.ts,.tsx src",
    "lint:check": "eslint --ext .js,.cjs,.ts,.tsx src --fix",
    "cs": "prettier --write .",
    "cs:check": "prettier --check .",
    "prepare": "husky install",
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.8.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.8.0",
    "@faker-js/faker": "7.6.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.11",
    "@types/copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/lodash.groupby": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.24",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/sanitize-html": "^2.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.17.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^1.3.1",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.27.0",
    "allure-mocha": "^2.13.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
    "branch-name-lint": "^2.1.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^6.2.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "js-image-generator": "^1.0.4",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "madge": "^6.1.0",
    "mocha": "^10.3.0",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "msw": "^2.2.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "playwright": "^1.41.2",
    "playwright-core": "^1.41.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.9",
    "react-select-event": "^5.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "testrail-mocha-reporter": "^0.5.4",
    "tinymce": "5.10.9",
    "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "twin.macro": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.1.5",
    "vite-bundle-visualizer": "^0.10.0",
    "vite-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.21.0",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^4.2.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.2",
    "vitest": "^1.3.1",
    "vitest-canvas-mock": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.1.0"
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "types": ["vitest/globals", "vite-plugin-svgr/client"],

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "types/**/*"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, I have `tsconfig.node.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

I have checked my project for circular dependencies with help of `madge` and fixed all of them, and it didn't help.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is somehow `tsc` might be catching `node_modules` which stalls it. Can you also include your `tsconfig` if possible in your question. Or try excluding `node_modules` https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude

Comment: Sure, I'll include my tsconfig.

Comment: This is very strange we use 95% similar setup, even the versions, I also used your TS config files on my big project and everything works, could not make it to stall. I will try few more things and let you know if I manage to reproduce. Another assumption I have is, it might be catching some TS files it should not somehow if you updated or upgraded some deps very recently. Try running it without `--watch` flag tho

Comment: @mssp the worst thing is that we didn't have `tsc` command before build, and because of that, we haven't run it for a while... Now it's hard to troubleshoot after which package update it happened. By the way, I run `tsc` without `--watch` flag, result is the same as before.